# How to get quarter of year if we have month number?

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of finding the quarter number from the month number using floordiv or modulo or something else.

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(1,13) # 1,2,...,12
q = []
for i in m:
    if i <= 3: q.append(1)
    elif i <=6: q.append(2)
    elif i<=9: q.append(3)
    else: q.append(4)
    
q # [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
# note: there are four quarters in one year.
# month 123 are quarter 1 and so on.
```

Are there any elegant methods in python or numpy to do the same operation?

Comment: Something like `month_number//3 + 1`?

Comment: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]` i got this

Comment: As I wrote *something like*.  Obviously you need to make some further modifications, but they shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Yeah, i was also playing with `i//4 i//3 i%3 i//4+1 etc` but could not find the other method.

Comment: So you need to subtract 1 from the number before doing `//3` in order to shift the result sequence to the right by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `math.ceil` on the result of dividing the month number by 3:

```py
from math import ceil
q = [ceil(a / 3) for a in range(1, 13)]
print(q)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

The more general formula is:

```py
ceil(month_num / (12 / num_segments))
```

Alternatively:

```py
ceil(month_num * num_segments / 12)
```

Where `num_segments` is the number of segments you are dividing the year up into.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(1,13)
q = np.ceil(m/3).astype(int)
print(q)

# [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to set up classes for this sort of thing. I don't know if everyone will agree with me that it's more elegant in that if you are just writing a quick and dirty script you can do it in fewer lines with a simple `if elif else` block, but I would suggest the following is more 'Pythonic'.

```
import numpy as np
import math
class Month():
    def __init__(self, number=None):
        self.number = number

    def get_quarter(self):
        return ceil(self.number/3)

m = np.arange(1,13)
months = []
for i in m:
    months.append(Month(number=i))
q = []
for month in months:
    q.append(month.get_quarter())
```

Now... The answer you were probably looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import math
m = np.arrange(1,13)
q = []
for i in m:
    q.append(ceil(i/3))
```

Comment: I don't think this `Month` class is designed ideally; it should only store the month name and number, and then *calculate* the quarter on the fly. The way you have it set up, you have to trust that the code that instantiated the `Month` did the correct calculation for the quarter. So, `get_quarter()` should just return `ceil(self.number/3)`.

Comment: @RandomDavis Very good point, post corrected

Comment: Okay yeah looks fine now.

Comment: @RandomDavis Got rid of the name too since I was just including it to suggest, if you want to add this later, it's easier if you have it set up as a class, but it's not pertinent to the answer, and having quarter calculated by a method seems much more pythonic than a declaration to an attribute.

Comment: Okay I made a couple of edits if you don't mind, there was no need to use `int()` (correct me if I'm wrong but I believe `ceil()` always returns an `int`, based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil)). I also added a missing closed parenthesis. Also I replaced a stray `month.quarter` with `month.get_quarter()`.

Comment: @RandomDavis Appreciate it! I did a quick google on the ceil since - although intuitively the whole *point* of ceil is to round up, and therefore get a whole number(dynamically cast as an int if not explicitly by the function) - I don't use the function often in python [rather I was relying on my understanding from maths] and the SO post I found actually had the result being returned as `300.0` and I erroneously assumed that was right, hence the int. All in all, thank you for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a math formula in q to get quarter. Every language has integer division. The + 2 is offset to ensure 1 is lowest returned value. Otherwise answers would be returned (0, 1, 2, 3)

Change m to desired month. You will always get correct quarter

```
m = 2
q = (m + 2) \ 3
```